# print out of java web application from server side script

Tags: java, jsp, printing

I want to take print out a the JSP file using serverside java code.

Currently I am using javascript code, but want to get rid of using client side scripting because it won't work if user disables javascript in browser.
I am using:

```
window.print();
```

Is there any way to do this? If yes, I also want to set the default printer and not to display print dialog box and take print using the default printer.

Comment: You want to print something from server after your page renders without a client script? are you sure?

Comment: Since printing is to be performed on the client, you _will_ need something which is executed in the browser. JavaScript, Flash, or ActiveX come to mind. HTML cannot print itself.

Comment: @Harlandraka yes.., i want to take print out from printer of a jsp file when user clicks on 'print' button, Not using javascript but using java code

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you can't, Java is a server side language, you need to use a client side language if you want your page to dinamically change after it is rendered.

However, you have an option that in my opinion it's pretty ugly.

Create a file on the server and make it start with

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="2;url="/>
</head>
```

so that your page will refresh every 2 (or whatever you want) seconds. Then, on the server-side script, append to it the code you have to print out, then, in your main webpage, make an iframe that points to it.

The result:

Your page will refresh every 2 seconds, and it will contain all the html you previously added to your file with java

I hope it was clear, if it is not, please ask :)

Comment: you take it completely wrong.. i need to take printout of rendered jsp file from printer using java code, i dont want to use window.print() , a javascript code.

Comment: you can't, because the printout of the java class is on the server, and not on the client, the client only receives the html produced by your jsp, nothing more.

Comment: @f_puras He is asking about how to catch the printstream from the server and use it on the client, he is not talking about applets. And if he wants to make an applet it would be really bad, he should use javascript instead, because it is true that javascript could be disabled on the browser, but what if he writes an applet and the client does not even have the java plugin?

Comment: @Harlandraka I understand it the way you do - yet the OP doesn't, so I try and come up with all I can think of. Of course it is absurd to use an applet here, but if the OP definitely wants to use Java ;-)

Comment: @Harlandraka thanx for the reply... its not possible ,the way i want to do

Comment: @f_puras thanx for the reply... its not possible ,the way i want to do :)